# Google Colaboratory - Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I get the MessageError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded when I try to upload a json file and I assume the problem is the size.

I'm trying to upload a 187Kb json file on Google Colaboratory using the function files.upload(), but it gives me the error "MessageError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded." When I try to upload manually on the sidebar, it just keeps loading endlessly. Is the another way to upload this file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload it to Google Drive first. Then call mount to access Google drive content.

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('drive')
# your file should be in drive/My\ Drive/
```

Comment: This certainly is one option.  The problem for me is that I have far more space available locally then I do on google drive.  Otherwise, I would stick with this option all the time.

Answer (score 0):

What I did in response to this error message since I did not want it to count against my Google Drive quota is I uploaded the file in the left pane (labeled "Files") of the Google Colab notebook.  The drawback to this is that the file will be gone when the notebook is recycled, however it does get the job avoiding both upload and Google Drive caps.